Office script-Pivot Table-Pivot table options
I have created a pivot table on an excel table using office script. but in pivot table few cells are blank or null i want them to be replaced with zero.
just like manually we do in pivot table options-Layout and format-for empty cells should show -0
i want this to be done via office script .
eg. here forth row More than 7 Days is blank it should show 0
Pending score AO Kolhapur
Count of REF_NUM
Column Labels
Row Labels
Less than 8 Days
More than 7 Days
Grand Total
RBO SOLAPUR
15
15
ICHALKARANJI
5
8
13
Reply
pivot table options-Layout and format-for empty cells should show -0
same should be done via offce script

Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question to use markdown formatting for the tables.
